# whats the difference between so_reuseaddr and net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse

Tags: tcp, network-programming

To me,it seems that this two things are implied in the same way in the net kernel.
May some one tell me the truth in detail,or here is a ref to some book like tcp/ip.vol2

Answer (score 0):

`tcp_tw_reuse` is a kernel-space variable that means that the kernel can reuse TCP ports which are in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

`SO_REUSEADDR` is a user-space socket option that means that the kernel can reuse UDP ports which are in any state as long as the other users have also set this option on the corresponding sockets.

In other words they have practically nothing in common.